# Add columns in an existing databse through Doctrine Symfony framework

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

To add a column in an existing db, I followed this documentation of Doctrine Migrations.
http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/doctrine/1_2/en/07-Migrations

I successfully ran all the commands and got the auto-generated file for which the documentation is asking. But while running the last command `"./symfony doctrine:migrate"`i got this error in command prompt:

- SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'VARCHAR(100), value TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(key)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8 '` at line 1. Failing Query: `"CREATE TABLE hs_hr_config (key VARCHAR(100), value TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(key)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8 ENGINE = INNODB"`

These two are the places where `"hs_hr_config"` table has been created:
`create table`hs_hr_config`(`
key`varchar(100) not null default '',`
value`varchar(512) not null default '',
    primary key (`key`)
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8;`

`CREATE TABLE hs_hr_config (`key`VARCHAR(100), value TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`key`)) ENGINE = INNODB;`

Is anyone having any idea how to eliminate this error???

One more problem:
when I run the following command:
php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
I get the error like "could not find the input file-app/console" . Why I am getting this error???

Any valuable guidance will b highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Key` is a reserved word. Try putting `key` in quotes like `'key'`.

Alternatively you could change the name of the column in your mapping so that it is not using a reserved word but still maps to your property. This approach would also stop any issues being created if you create any future migrations using the offending field names.

In yaml you would do..

```
fields:
    key:
        column: my_key
        type: string
```

Also see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: thanks for your attention. I tried to rename the column but its not working. It seems to be an access violation error, because the project on which I am working is built by some other person. I think I need to first change the username and password for the db to access it. Do you have any idea how to do it??

Comment: If you have changed the mapping then your would need to create another diff. What makes you think it's an access violation? Granted it says access violation in the error but it also says syntax error and then follows it up with more in depth info about the syntax error "**Syntax error** or access violation 1064 **You have an error in your SQL syntax**;... details about the specific syntax error ..."

Comment: Actually in my project only root user is allowed to modify database, and i was not modifying it as root user. This made me think that its an access violation error.